# Can I partially implement an interface hierarchy?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I am writing an interface similar to this:

```
class BaseInterface
{
    virtual void MethodA() = 0;
}

class DerivedInterface : public BaseInterface
{
    virtual void MethodB() = 0;
}
```

I want to create a class `Derived` which is-a `DerivedInterface` (and, implicitly, is-a `BaseInterface`, particularly a `Base`). That is, I only want to have to define `MethodB` however in the class `Derived` - I want to partially specify the interface (namely, `MethodA`) somewhere else.

```
class Base : public BaseInterface
{
    virtual void MethodA() {...};
}

class Derived : public DerivedInterface // somehow include Base as well
{
    void MethodB() {...};
}
```

Is this possible in C++?

Comment: Forgot `virtual` in there?

Comment: If it's not in the inheritance chain of `Derived` it won't work, and I'm pretty sure a diamond-shaped chain won't work here either.  (ie.  something like `class Derived : public Base, public DerivedInterface`)

Comment: but is it really required? I mean virtual keyword isn't that implicit!

Comment: @BhupeshPant: By default, member functions are non virtual in C++, so you have to be explicit about it, at least when first declaring one.

Comment: yeah but if you are deriving from a class then all the virtual member functions will always be virtual throughout all inheritance hierarchy..Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: @BhupeshPant As I said, when you first declare a virtual member function, you have to use the keyword. In derived classes, you don't have to repeat the keyword. But if you do not use the keyword `virtual` and define a function with the same signature in a derived class, you won't be happy with the result.

Comment: !@blackbird Even I hold the same opinion, so whats the difference..I am saying that in the derived class he do not have to mention virtual keyword again..

Comment: @BhupeshPant In the first version of this question, there wasn't any `virtual` at all, so in reply to your first comment ("is it really required?") I said: Yes, it is required. I'm glad we both know how to declare virtual functions.

Comment: Yes. Even I felt that I missed some thing in between :).. Thanks! and welcome in "SO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With virtual inheritance, to avoid duplications of members:

```
class BaseInterface
{
    public:
    virtual void MethodA() = 0;
};

class DerivedInterface : virtual public BaseInterface
{
    public:
    virtual void MethodB() = 0;
};

class Base : virtual public BaseInterface
{
    public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void MethodA() {};
};

class Derived : public Base, virtual public DerivedInterface
{
    public:
    virtual void MethodB() {};
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.MethodA();
    d.MethodB();
}
```

Without virtual inheritance Derived has two MethodA and an additional override in Derived is needed:

```
virtual void MethodA() override { Base::MethodA(); }
```

That defeats the interface design, though!

It might be cleaner not to have a derived interfaces:

```
class FirstInterface;
class SecondInterface;
class Base : public virtual FirstInterface;
class Derived : public Base, virtual public SecondInterface;
```

This avoids the duplication, even without virtual inheritance. (To avoid trouble down the road, I would use virtual interface inheritance, too)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance is the perfect answer for it.

```
class Derived : public Base, virtual public DerivedInterface
{
    public:
    virtual void MethodB() {};
};
```

Now you have both the members...

Comment: This is not correct, refer to Dieter Lücking's answer to see how it can be done.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is still not correct, refer to Dieter Lücking's answer to see where to use virtual inheritance.